# fitvid.js stops working on the second page of the infinite scroll (jquery isotope)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I'm using the jquery isotope plugin (and infinite scrolling) + fitvids.js in a layout. I got it working for the most part but the problem is with the videos contained in the pages loaded with infinite scrolling.

Vids #1 and #2 in the first page are being resized

Vid #3 in the second page loaded with the infinite scroll plugin is being ignored

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// start fitvids.js
$(".video").fitVids();

// start isotope
var $container = $('#wrapper');
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.post'
        });

    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
        nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '.post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
            img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
          }
        },
        // call Isotope as a callback
        function(newElements){
            var $newElems = $(newElements);
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $('#wrapper').isotope( 'appended', $newElems );
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Linked page gets a 404, but seems like you need to call `$(".video").fitVids();` again after loading new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right steveax, thanks. Here's the new code

```
function(newElements){
  var $newElems = $(newElements);
  $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $('#wrapper').isotope( 'appended', $newElems );
      $('.video').fitVids('appended', $newElems);  
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the 'appended' part for? is it related to isotope or infinite scroll?  And thanks so much for posting your solution.  This just saved me quite a bit of time.