# JQuery Infinite Scroll Help - passing variables to second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

Problem: I have implemented an infinitescroll plugin in my rails app, along with JQuery Masonry. It works perfectly but I am facing one little problem: starting from the second page, the `hover` function does not get triggered. This problem is very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724698/fitvid-js-stops-working-on-the-second-page-of-the-infinite-scroll-jquery-isotop) on Stackoverflow. I'm supposed to call my hover function again after the Masonry callback.

**My original code:**

```
<script>    
$(function () {
    var $container = $('#container_masonry');

    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '.pagination'
        nextSelector: '.pagination a',
        itemSelector: '.image_masonry'
        loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'Done loading'
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
    },
        // trigger Masonry as a callback
        function(newElements) {
            //hide new items while loading
            var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });
            //images must be loaded completely before adding to layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                //they are loaded and ready to be showed
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );  
            });
        }
    );

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.image_masonry',
        columnWidth: 10,
        isAnimated: true,
        animationOptions: { duration: 400 },
        isResizable: true,
        isFitWidth: true
        });

        $('.image_masonry').hover(
        function(){
        $('.title',this).fadeIn();
        $('.like_num',this).show();
        var buttonDiv= $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
        }, function(){
        $('.title',this).fadeOut();
        $('.like_num',this).hide();
        var buttonDiv= $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
```

I should add the following,

```
        $('.image_masonry').hover(
        function(){
        $('.title',this).fadeIn();
        $('.like_num',this).show();
        var buttonDiv= $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
        }, function(){
        $('.title',this).fadeOut();
        $('.like_num',this).hide();
        var buttonDiv= $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
        });
```

to right after,

```
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                //they are loaded and ready to be showed
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                //ADD HOVER FCN HERE
```

However, simply adding the whole hover function did not work. I'm new to jQuery so I'm not entirely sure, but I need to pass in the related variables along with the function for it to work (got this hint from the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724698/fitvid-js-stops-working-on-the-second-page-of-the-infinite-scroll-jquery-isotop). So I should add something like

```
        $('.image_masonry').hover(
        function(SOME-RELATED-VARIABLES){
        $('.title',this).fadeIn();
        $('.like_num',this).show();
        var buttonDiv= $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
        }, function(SOME-RELATED-VARIABLES){
        $('.title',this).fadeOut();
        $('.like_num',this).hide();
        var buttonDiv= $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
        });
```

But I need someone to teach me what I should put in there. I'm struggling because of my lack of familiarity with jQuery. I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: I could be wrong in my guess and the problem lies in something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing some commas between rows 5-11. Also if you're loading external content at a later time, you need to delegate the hover event with `on` or `delegate` depending on your version. I added `on` below.

```
$(function () {
  var $container = $('#container_masonry');

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '.pagination',
    nextSelector: '.pagination a',
    itemSelector: '.image_masonry',
    loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'Done loading',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function (newElements) {
    //hide new items while loading
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    //images must be loaded completely before adding to layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
      //they are loaded and ready to be showed
      $newElems.animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
      $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
    });
  });

  $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.image_masonry',
      columnWidth: 10,
      isAnimated: true,
      animationOptions: {
        duration: 400
      },
      isResizable: true,
      isFitWidth: true
    });

    $('body').on({
      mouseenter: function () {
        $('.title', this).fadeIn();
        $('.like_num', this).show();
        var buttonDiv = $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
      },
      mouseleave: function () {
        $('.title', this).fadeOut();
        $('.like_num', this).hide();
        var buttonDiv = $(this).children('.button');
        buttonDiv.toggle();
      }
    }, '.image_masonry');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does solve the problem very well. Could you explain a bit about "delegating" and why you replaced hover with mouseenter and leave?

Comment: @MaximusS http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ delegating makes it so any data loaded into a container (in this case `$('body')`) gets whatever event handlers added to it. Normally once the script finishes running if any new data is loaded it will not have got the event handlers because it was loaded after the script loaded. Delegation takes javascript events. `hover` is a function in jquery just used for easy access of the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` which you can see here: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=hover